# How to check if any array element is not holding a specific string

Tags: arrays, bash, element

Is there a way of checking all the elements in an array, and `if` all the elements in the array are not holding a string `mystring` to return true? For example, if any element of an array with 2 elements is holding `mystring` I want it to make it return as false, anything else is true:

```
[mystring][mystring] = false/don't do anything
[mystring][A] = false/don't do anything
[@#$2][mystring]=false/don't do anything
[asda][wrwe]=true
```

**Q:** How can check an array with *n* elements, if none of the elements within that array hold any other value other then `mystring` it should return true?

My attempt was:

```
    for element_number in `seq 0 $going_through_the_elements_of_the_array`;
    do
          my_var=${the_array[$element_number]}


                if ! [[ $my_var == "$my_string" ]]
                then
                     echo " This should be printed"
                     exit
                fi
    done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
case ${the_array[@]}
in
  *my string*) echo "true" ;;
  *) echo "false" ;;
esac
```

It expands the array into a single string then uses the RE mechanism in the case statement to search for your target.  The case where it is found prints true, all other cases print false.